# Node API not fetching data from database for specific values

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following API in express

```
app.get('/getfirstpqi/:routeId/:year', (req,res) => {   
    const sqc = sqlConn;
    const { routeId,year } = req.params;
   //console.log(routeId)
  // console.log(year)
    let query = `
    SELECT Age,PSR,PSRType,AADT,Esals,CumEsal FROM dbo.PF_FutureViewTable where RouteId= `+routeId+` and YEAR(ReportedYear)=`+year;
    console.log(query);
    let params = [];
    sqc.SqlExecuteStatementCallback(
        query, params, null, (data) => {

            res.send(data);
        });
});
```

This API is not fetching data for some specific values of the parameters. But correctly fetching data for rest of them. And the data is present in the database. When I executed the query directly in the database it showed me the result. Any suggestion is really appreciated.

Comment: What parameters are you passing when you don't get the data in return?

Comment: Never Mind its a bad question. I noticed just now that one of the values is missing in the database for which the query is not executed correctly.